# Error on last element of NSArray obis command with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN

Tags: ios, nsarray, objective-c-blocks

I am getting this error `"EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN"` when Xcode reaches the last "`nil`" statement to identify the end of the NSArray* objs.

I have seen other comments similar errors [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156152/app-crashed-due-to-change-in-datamodel) and [here](http://www.splinter.com.au/what-do-do-with-excarmdaalign-on-an-iphone-ap/) but those do not seem related to what I am encountering. Is it something obvious that I am missing? Has anyone else encountered this?

Thanks

```
                                NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:ATHLETEID, CURRENTGRADE, EVENTNAME,
                                                 PERSONALREC, SEASONSBEST, EVENTMARK, MEETDATE, MEETID, MEETNAME,
                                                 EVENTPLACE, SEASON_NAME,
                                                 SORTMARK,TYPE, RESULTID, nil];

                                NSArray *objs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                 athleteID,
                                                 t_currentGrade,
                                                 t_eventName,
                                                 t_eventPR,
                                                 t_eventSB,
                                                 t_markInEvent,
                                                 t_meetDate,
                                                 t_meetID,
                                                 t_meetName,
                                                 t_placeInEvent,
                                                 t_currentSeason,
                                                 t_sortMark,
                                                 t_typeOfEvent,
                                                 t_uniqueResultID,nil];

                                NSMutableDictionary *resultsFromSingleMeet [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                                                              initWithObjects:objs
                                                                                      forKeys:keys];
```

Here is the dump from my Debug Navigator:

```
Thread 1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread
Thread 2, Queue : com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 4, Queue : Athlete fetcher
#0  0x2e1bc79c in CFRetain ()
#1  0x2e1ca760 in +[__NSArrayI __new:::] ()
#2  0x2e1c7f04 in -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] ()
#3  0x2e1fdbdc in +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:] ()
#4  0x00034290 in __84+[MarksFromMeets(FromAthleticNet) fetchAthleteMarksIntoDatabase:whereIDofAthleteIs:]_block_invoke at /Users/Phlipo/Documents/iOS_Programming/ITrackPerformance/ITrackPerformance/MarksFromMeets+FromAthleticNet.m:293
#5  0x38ad00c2 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#6  0x38ad4e7a in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#7  0x38ad1f92 in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#8  0x38ad5744 in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#9  0x38ad59c4 in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
#10 0x38bffdfe in _pthread_wqthread ()
```

Comment: What are the types of the object you are adding to the arrays? I am guessing you are adding primitive types (e.g NSUInteger or int) instead of objects. Make sure to wrap all numbers in NSNumber object.

Comment: Thanks Joel and @Kumar for your help. I would have been spinning my wheels in the wrong direction otherwise!

Joel if you put your comment in form of an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are adding primitive types (e.g `NSUInteger` or `int`) to your array, instead of objects. Make sure to wrap all numbers in `NSNumber` object.

Answer (score 1):

The **error** shows that, You are about to adding the `incompatible value type to the objects`.

> Check(Ensure) the values of Objects & Keys has a value of Object(Null Value) before its
>   get added.

Comment: Thanks Kumar. Your comments were helpful.