# Adding a new entity to core data and populating some values

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, migration

I am updating my core data model in the next version of my app. I have added a new entity for 'Departments', following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830079/iphone-core-data-automatic-lightweight-migration).

I would like to add some sample departments, both for new users and those who update to the latest version. My approach up till now has been to store a 'HasLaunchedOnce' boolean in `[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults]`, which if missing adds some reference data and sets itself to YES for the next launch.

Should I add a similar flag (hasLaunchedV1.1Once) to add my departments? What other approaches could I take? My goal is to keep things as simple as possible for future versions. I would prefer to simply check if any departments exist, but of course this would fire if the user had deleted all departments manually.

Comment: Well, if you have a created a versioned core data model then you could just save the same version in the userdefaults so that you will know what version of your model is the user using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is valid in principle.

Just take into account that the `NSManagedObjectModel` class has an instance method `versionIdentifiers`. You could also use this to find out what the latest version is.