# iOS: backup core data and restore with newer model version

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

How can I backup my core data objects created in version 1 and restore them in version 2? Simply copy the .sqlite-file won't work if the model changes... Is there a way to backup the file restore it and then start the migration?

Comment: Why? Are your model changes too complicated for the automatic light-weight migration to work?

Comment: no, they are not (yet?). but I can't replace the sqlite with the old one, can I? I mean while the app is running, e.g. the user taps on "restore backup" and then the restoring should happen.

Comment: Why not? I mean, you'd have to remove any "open" managed object contexts before you did it, but when you open it it would automatically perform the migration again.

Comment: How can this be achieved with Magical Record? What are the steps before and after copying the sqlite-file? And do I have to copy all three files? (.sqlite, .sqlite-shm, .sqlite-wal?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Solved it with MagicalRecord the following way:

1. `[MagicalRecord cleanUp];`
2. copy .sqlite, .sqlite-shm, .sqlite-wal over to the new place
3. `[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:sqliteFileName];`

finished - works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate your database using Automatic Lightweight Migration.

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html

[iPhone Core Data "Automatic Lightweight Migration"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830079/iphone-core-data-automatic-lightweight-migration)