# IOS 8 Adding new attribute to Excistig entity in new version of App?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, ios8, xcode6

I have created an App in IOS with a core-data with in it, I lunched it into iTunes with no problems(1.2). This was able to download fine from iTunes and worked fine. I then updated core-data with a new attribute, and after testing on Emulator released it as a new version(1.3) to which I had no problems lunching in iTunes.

When downloading New Version of App on device the App would crash to a slash screen.
After knowing this I ran this on Emulator to find crash due to core-data. Its seems to have crashed due to me adding a new attribute, please can anyone help with this i would be for ever grateful?

Comment: Could you post the crash dump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have given theoretical statement of your problem. I suggest you better try hands on : Core data migration strategies.

The light weight coredata migration referencing guides are best at popular [raywinderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration).
and [Custom core data migration](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-migration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for getting back to me I had since fixed the problem with the link below, I should of read up on light weight migration before the post, but your right thank you.

[iPhone Core Data "Automatic Lightweight Migration"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830079/iphone-core-data-automatic-lightweight-migration)